# Scope of Python globals in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

What is the scope or lifespan of a global variable in AWS Lambda?

for example if I do something like this:

```
cache = {}

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   # do something with "cache"
   # do something else with "cache"
```

Is `cache` going to be initialized once per *invocation* (fresh process for each Lambda execution) or once this module is initialized, is it re-used for multiple invocations?

Comment: Worth a deeper dive by reading James Beswick's 3-part blog post on Operating Lambda, [part 1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/), [part 2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-2/), and [part 3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-3/).

Comment: No matter how fast you make the common case with caches and pools, you can't prevent those horrible 1000ms or more requests from happening sometimes. You can use provisioned concurrency to keep at least one worker up for critical lambda functions, forcing global variables to live very long in that lambda function. In theory cold starts would be nearly eliminated when caused by idling.

Answer (score 12):

Global variables retain their value between invocations in the same execution environment.

Libraries should be defined in the initialization code outside of the handler, so they are loaded once when the execution environment is created.

source [aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/global-scope.html)

```
import boto3, json

client = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')
tbl = client.Table('my-dynamo-table')

mydata = {}
mydata["groups"] = []

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if len(mydata["groups"]) == 0:
        # data is not cached, make call to dynamo
        data = tbl.scan()
        group_data = data['Items']

        for group in group_data:
            mydata["groups"].append(group['name'])
        return mydata

    else:
        # return cached content
        return mydata
```

Take advantage of execution environment reuse to improve the performance of your function. Initialize SDK clients and database connections outside of the function handler, and cache static assets locally in the /tmp directory. Subsequent invocations processed by the same instance of your function can reuse these resources. This saves cost by reducing function run time.

[aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/best-practices.html)

Comment: I want to have global vars per invocation and do not want to share my 'cache' object between any parallel invocations. Is it possible ?

Comment: workaround: you can put all code inside your lambda_handler in another function running from process. So you must not have side effect

Answer (score 5):

Lambda Global Variables do not get updated with every invocation. Whatever you write inside the handler function will get invoked with each invocation.

Coming to lifespan of Global Variables, it stays as long as the initialized container stays up ( it shutdowns the container if it remains inactive for certain period.of time) or code is modified and redeployed. We should be cautios of what we are putting up as cache, i.e if the cached data is updated frequently then storing it up in cache is not a good idea.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-context.html

https://medium.com/tensult/aws-lambda-function-issues-with-global-variables-eb5785d4b876

Comment: Thanks, I think the critical information is whether the "initialized container" refers to the Python process, or just the OS/Linux container that runs the Python process.