# share db session across multiple lambda invocations using Mangum

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi

So far, I've been declaring my db connection outside of my web server app creation:

```py
# src/main.py
db_session = ... # connection 
app = FastAPI()
handler = Mangum(app)

# other files would import db_session from src.main
# and query the db through it
```

For better unit testing, I decided to move the db declaration as part of the app state:

```py
def create_app(settings: Settings):
    app = FastApi()
    app.state.config = settings
    app.state.db_session = ... # here is the db declaration, using `settings` to get db credentials
    ...
    return app

app = create_app(settings)
handler = Mangum(app)
```

does anyone know if, by wrapping the app around `Mangum`, db session won't be shared anymore across multiple lambda invocations ? I don't know to which extent `app` here is within the handler real code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good answer citing the AWS documentation here: [Scope of Python globals in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68368363/6485881)

In your case, `app` is a global variable and anything connected to it should stay global. Passing it onto the function call (or class constructor) of Mangum won't change that.

I'm not familiar with Mangum, but unless it does some sort of trickery, it should be a regular global variable.

Comment: That’s actually the question raised here, I wonder if some trickery happens (since the handler is returned from Mangum, db « could be » not part of the global scope)

Comment: Is your question if your code change, changed the behavior, or if Mangum changes the behavior? If it's #1 - no, if #2 that's a completely different question.

Comment: #2 here,
I thought it was clear from the title (no offense here, maybe it wasn't really readable)

Comment: You're showing two different code samples that are doing the same thing in a slightly different way, I got the impression that you wanted to know if they have different effects :D